How to display FluentValidation validation on Razor page for Mediatr Command field that is not displayed on page
I am working on a project that has Razor pages, Mediatr, and FluentValidation in the tech stack. For one page, the Mediatr Command object contains a Dictionary similar to the following:
public record Command(
  short? ID,
  string? Item1,
  string? Item2,
  ...
  Dictionary<string, string> AList
) :IRequest<Result<>>

The corresponding validator has code similar to the following:
  public class CommandValidator : AbstractValidator<Command>
  {
    public CommandValidator()
    {
      RuleFor(x => x.Item1)
          .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a value.")
          .MaximumLength(40).WithMessage("Item 1 must be 40 characters or less.");
      RuleFor(x => x.Item2)
          .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must enter a value.")
          .MaximumLength(40).WithMessage("Item 2 must be 25 characters or less.");
      ...
      RuleFor(x => x.AList)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("This list cannot be empty.");
    }
  } 

AList gets populated by selecting items from a pair of select lists, so there is no input field specific to AList.  The other fields on the Command object have input fields associated with them.  For example:
<textbox For="Data.Item1" />
<textbox For="Data.Item2" />  (textbox is a custom tag helper)

So when I try to save data with the required data missing, the validations are displaying as expected except for the validation for AList. I have confirmed that the validation for AList is returned among the others in the results from Mediatr.Send().  I am assuming it is not displaying because AList itself is not part of the page as the other items?
How the data in AList is displayed is via a partial with code similar to this fragment:
   @foreach (var item in Model.Data.AList)
   {
       <input type="hidden" name="Data.OrgList[@item.Key]" value="@item.Value" />
       <p>@item.Value</p>
   }

So if AList is empty, no items are displayed.  If the user chooses to save with no items, then the validation should show up.  As noted above, the failed validation is coming back in the results, so the user is not able to save.  The validation just does not display to indicate why the save failed.  Is there a way to wire this up to get this validation to display?
Also, as mentioned earlier, AList is populated with selections from two select lists. The content of the second can vary depending on the selection from the first.  The HTML for them is similar to the following:
   <dropdown For="SelectListData.Parent" items="@Model.GetSelectListData.Parents!" label="Parent" hx-post="@Url.Page("Create", "PopulateChildren")" hx-target="#parents" />
   <dropdown For="SelectListData.Child" items="@Model.GetSelectListData.Children!" label="Child" hx-post="@Url.Page("Create", "PopulateAList")" hx-target="#parents" />

Ideally, it would be good to have validations on these as well to tell the user an item should be selected from each list when one has not. I'm thinking that since the for of each dropdown is a different model than the Model.Data used for other things like AList, the validations will not work.  Instead, these need to get pulled into the same view Model.Data is using?
Thanks in advance for the help on this.

We have come up with a possible solution.  The following  was added at the place we wanted the validation to display.  This along with the existing code in the validator now displays a validation message when the list is empty.
 <div><span asp-validation-for="DataAList"></span></div>
Not sure if there is a better solution but this is working.  Since this is working, we have decided we do not need the additional validations on the select lists as mentioned in the original post.
